# Не собирает данные, Селениум

Tags: python, парсер, selenium

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в общем захожу по ссылке, начинаю парсить, но данных нет
вот код в link1 просто беру первую ссылку из списка, для теста

```
   categorys = get_category(src)
    #print(*categorys, sep='\n')
    link1 = categorys[0][1]['href']
    html = driver.get(link1)
    time.sleep(25)
    #парсим данные
    def get_content(url):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'lxml')
        items = soup.find_all('div', class_='product-wrapper')
        products = []
        for item in items:
            products.append({
                'product_name': item.find('a', class_='product-title').get_text(),
                'product_sklad': item.find('div', class_=['available', 'unavailable']).get_text(),
                'product_code': item.find('div', class_='product-code').get_text(),
                'product_cost': item.find('div', class_="product-price").get_text()
            })
        return products

    content = get_content(html)
    print(*content, sep='\n')
```

Как собрать данные?

Comment: Кажется этот вопрос уже был. И там высказывали мысль, что может быть все генерится жаваскриптом. Ну да, для этого нужен селениум, но извлекать тоже им, а не BeautifulSoup

Comment: дело в том, что я селениумом прохожу авторизацию, в итоге ссылки категорий я собрал, но потом, в подкатегории, когда надо собирать данные о товаре данных нет. Вроде натолкнули на мысль, что при заходе на каждую ссылку надо подгружать кукисы. По идее данные появились. Надо проверить по всем ссылкам.

Comment: с кукисами сработало вроде..